# Java Retrieve date records in correct format from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, timezone

I have a table which was populated by a excel. The date in the columns shows according to my system's timezone when a select query is run in mysql.
But when i run the same query in java using jdbc connection, i am not getting the correct values as which was present in the excel.
I know it is a issue with the timezone. Please guide me with the changes that need to be done for the select query

Result of the following queries are NULL.

> SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone;
>
> SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_name;

Just to elaborate on the issue, when i run a select query on date in mysql server, i get the right date values for a column. But when i run the same through a java program, i get converted values to a different timezone.

THe java code is as follows:-

```
resultList=(List<FosProd>)getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select fe, count(ldcfe) as Ttlv,  count(IF(ldcfe='PTP',1,NULL)) as PTP,DAY(ludfe) as dayte from (select FOS_NAME as fe,Last_Disposition_Code_FOS as ldcfe,Last_Updated_Date_FOS as ludfe from kic.master_mis group by ALLOCATION_DATE,ALLOCATION_BUCKET,BILLED_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,TOTAL_OUTSTANDING) as s1 where monthname(ludfe)=\"NOVEMBER\" GROUP BY MONTH(ludfe), DAY(ludfe),fe;", FosProd.class).getResultList();
```

DAY function in SELECT is providing me converted values.
Please help.

```
public class FosProd implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "fe")
    private String fe;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Ttlv")
    private long ttlv;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "PTP")
    @Id
    private long ptp;
    @Column(name = "dayte")
    private Integer dayte;
```

Comment: What was in the Excel? What is in the DB? What so you get in Java? Anything that might provide some clue to what your issue is?????

Comment: Excel is a Msexcel Spreadsheet. DB is mysql database. Just to elaborate on the issue, when i run a select query on date in mysql server, i get the right date values. But when i run the same through a java program, i get converted values.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, it's the JDBC driver "helping" you out, altering the `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` values because it's making adjustments to those values because of a difference in the timezone setting of the MySQL server and the JVM.

To see the timezone in effect for your connection to the MySQL server:

```
SELECT @@time_zone
```

Compare that to the timezone used by the JVM. If those are the *same*, then the JDBC driver shouldn't be making any adjustments to the values. If those are different, then it's likely that the JDBC driver is making timezone adjustments to the values.

---

**Change JDBC Connection settings**

We had to configure some options on the JDBC connection (MySQL J/Connector) url to stop the JDBC driver from doing brain dead timezone conversions, I think the most important change we made was:

```
useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

I think we also had to set `noTimezoneConversionForDateType=true` so timezone adjustments were't made on pure `DATE` datatypes.

I believe we also did some experimentation with custom mappings, between SQL datatypes and JDBC datatypes. But I don't think those ended up as part of our solution.)

(And obviously, this won't apply if you are using the MariaDB JDBC driver; we're just guessing that you're using MySQL J/Connector.)

**NOTE:** I'm not saying this is a solution to the issue being reported. The problem description provided in the question is *very* vague. There's no possible way for anyone to recommend a "solution" based on the information in the question.

---

**Other approaches**

That's not the only approach to addressing the issue, there are several other avenuesl suitability of these approaches really depends on your requirements, and what you are trying to achieve.

One "easy" button (probably *not* the most appropriate solution for you) would be to modify the timezone of the JVM to match the timezone of the MySQL server. BUT... that's going to impact a whole boatload more than just timezone adjustments made by JDBC Driver.

Another "patch" would be to *not* return `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` expressions in the `SELECT`, but return expressions that have a *character* datatype instead. That will make the JDBC driver "bypass" any timezone adjustments is doing on DATETIME, (BUT... you'll be returning values that will be mapped into `String`, not `Date` or `Calendar` objects.  e.g.

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mydatecol,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS mydate_string
   FROM
```

In a similar vein, you could return the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mydatecol)`, and that's going to return an integer (number of seconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970 UTC). The value return by that is going to be informed by the setting of the `time_zone` variable in the MySQL session.)

Again, that's likely not the most appropriate solution.

We assume that you are seeing the "correct" DATETIME values when you run a query against the MySQL server. What's most important here is knowing the setting of the `time_zone` variable in your MySQL session.

```
SELECT @@time_zone
```

---

Comment: `SELECT @@time_zone` returns SYSTEM. Also i tried to add the change my connection parameters to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kic?noTimezoneConversionForDateType=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` but still i m facing the same issue. I am not sure how to get the timezone for JVM

Comment: It worked. I changed the query to a JPA typed query and the DAY fuction returned the correct values. Not sure why a native query was not providing me correct values. Thanks for the information.. it did help me in other cases though...